# Why there is no option for using fragments when min sdk is above 2.3?

Tags: android, android-studio

In Android Studio if I select min sdk above the options for GridLayout, Fragments, Navigation Drawer and Action Bar disappears:

Min SDK 2.3.3:
[image: selected]

Min SDK 4.0:
[image: not selected]

Comment: Could be that Android Studio has a bug and doesn't know how to use the Support Library?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Why there is no option for using fragments when min sdk is above 2.3?

Three of those checkboxes are for adding the *backports* of `GridLayout`, fragments, and the action bar. You do not need the backports of `GridLayout` and the action bar when your minimum SDK version is set to 11 or higher.

There are two issues, though:

1. There are legitimate reasons for using the backport of fragments even on an API Level 14+ app, notably to support nested fragments
2. "Navigation Drawer" should be an option regardless of API level

IMHO, those are bugs in Android Studio. Bugs like this are why I do not recommend Android Studio to newcomers to Android -- it is still an "early-access preview" and will have more than its fair share of issues.

Comment: @MartínMarconcini: Agreed. Most people thinking "I should use Android Studio since that's the future" should probably right now be using IDEA. Less integration, but fewer odd behaviors that will cause confusion. And, since Android Studio is based on IDEA, much of what you learn for IDEA will transfer over to Android Studio when it is more mature.